# Connecting Windows's Monitor to mac mini

Tags: windows, mac

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, let me explain my question in detail first.
I have a Windows 7 Pc with 24 inch Monitor with Virtual machine installed to use Mac OS. So because I use mac using Virtual Machine, it runs very slow. I was wondering what would be the best solution to use mac + windows both with same monitor and easy to switch between macOs and windows just like Virtual Machine. I thought to buy mac mini as that is the cheapest mac os I can get but I'm not sure if it is possible to connect on same monitor? I hope you get my question

Comment: A monitor is a monitor.  You don't indicate any information about the monitor's connection to the computer.

Comment: so you mean I have to buy another monitor for mac mini?

Comment: I didn't say anything about having to purchase another monitor.  I asked a very specific question.  I suggest you update your question to include that information.

Comment: Sounds to me like you just want a basic [KVM switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). But it's hard to tell what your question is asking exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept that you are looking for is remote desktop sharing. One machine (your mac mini) runs without any monitor physically connected but is set up to share its desktop. When the machine boots up, it will listen for a remote desktop connect over your local network. The other machine (your windows pc) runs some software to connect to the remote and displays the session in a window much like a virtual machine. There are several ways to do this depending on the hosting software installed. Here's one [posting of someone's instructions for using VNC.](http://www.trickyways.com/2010/06/how-to-remotely-access-mac-from-pc/) You only need one physical monitor and keyboard/mouse. Another name for this setup is a headless system.

Comment: How did you figure out the author was asking about using a remote desktop client on their new mac mini?

Comment: Looks good. How about the speed? and one more question. when i buy mac mini, first i'll have to connect with the monitor then do the following steps for mac then disconnect monitor for mac mini and use windows again for remote desktop sharing?

Comment: I just realized, any options which doesn't require internet connect?

Comment: Some remote desktop software works over serial ports, as if you were using a modem connection. I suspect its unlikely the Mac would allow this.